# how to fix this? use a function based on the target of the button clicked

Tags: javascript

How can i code my calc function so that it subtracts 1 to the main counter if clicked on the "lower count" button or add 1 if clicked on the "add counter".

I could use separate functions for each one, but im trying to learn how to create a single functions that will work for both scenarios based on the value of the button clicked.

The issue is 100% in the if else statement line 17.

Code below.

```js
(function () {
  //create a main counter to store the calculations
  let value = 0;

  //variables to use as selectors

  const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
  const lower = document.querySelector(".prevBtn");
  const upper = document.querySelector(".nextBtn");

  //set the html text to the counter value
  counter.textContent = value;

  // function to add or subtract value
  let calc = function (event) {
  
  //here is my problem the target value please help 
    let target = event.target;
    if (target.classList.contains("Prevbtn")) {
      value -= 1;
      counter.textContent = value;
    } else {
      value += 1;
      counter.textContent = value;
    }
  };

  //add functionality to the buttons
  lower.addEventListener("click", calc);
  upper.addEventListener("click", calc);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <!-- bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- font awesome -->
    <script src="js/all.js"></script>
    <title>Counter Project</title>
    <style></style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row max-height align-items-center">
        <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 text-center main-container p-5">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase">counter</h1>
          <h1 id="counter"></h1>
          <div class="btn-container d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
            <button class="btn counterBtn prevBtn text-uppercase m-2">
              lower count
            </button>
            <button class="btn counterBtn nextBtn text-uppercase m-2">
              add count
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- script js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: typo, `prevBtn` is not the same as `Prevbtn`, fix that and it works

Answer (score -1):

typo, prevBtn is not the same as Prevbtn, fix that and it works

answer given by user CertainPerformance